# android layout load different image resources at orientation change

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to have a solution in xml or a keyword for what to search to solve my problem:

I have multiple screens. Each screen has his own xml in `layout` folder. For eg a part of the code :

```
   <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/headerLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@drawable/header" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btBack"
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="33dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:background="@drawable/bt_back"
             />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

now, I would like to change the  `"@drawable/header"` value runtime when is a rotation, prefferable to configure and Android change not me in Java code. The same thing is done with
`"@drawable/bt_back"`, which is a `bt_back.xml` file at `drawable` folder and has a selector. His content is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- selected state -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bt_back_pressed" android:state_pressed="true" android:state_selected="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bt_back_pressed" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bt_back_pressed" android:state_pressed="true" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <!-- unselected state (default) -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bt_back_normal"/>

</selector>
```

Now in folder what I want drawable-hdpi, drawable-ldpi, I just need to put those 2 files and the android system is auto-handling the image changes for pressed and normal state depending on user device dpi.

The same thing I would like to have for header for rotation from portrait and landscape. Eg it should alternate the header_port.png to header-land.png.

How is possible?  Any ideas?

I don't wand different .xml layout for landscape, nor digg in java code.
Maybe in different folder the resources for header, described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) ? port and land?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are able to create a drawable-land-hdpi directory. Put your landscape versions in the qualified folders and android should automatically load them for you.

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on @toadzky's answer, you can create a different drawable directory for any qualifier that you find on [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) Android Developer page, and put images with the same name in each, and android will automatically know which one to use.  The same is true for layouts in the layout (or layout-land, etc.) folder, value xml files (e.g., string resources--useful for localization--or themes), in the values folders, or any other things you normally find in the res folder.

It's also important to note that the way its precedence works (with respect to which directory it picks for resources) is, if I recall correctly, "first match after excluding all incompatible directories".

So, if you had only drawable-hdpi and drawable, and you had an mdpi device, it would eliminate all directories qualified with hdpi, and select from the remaining directories (so you'd end up with the version from the drawable folder).  Further explanation is found on the linked page, under "How Android Finds the Best-matching Resource".

Comment: +1, not the layout want to be in diff folder, but the header, I will try it, thanks